Bokeh Config File To Set Defaults Tools
In Bokeh, you can use a .yaml file to set default values for bokeh plot attributes. Is there a way to set the default tools for a plot using a .yaml file?
Within a script you can change the plot tools by usings something like
p = figure(tools = ['box_zoom'])
I tried the following in a config file.
attrs:
    Plot:
        toolbar: ['fullscreen','pan','box_zoom','copy','save','reset','ywheel_zoom']

This gives me the error " expected an instance of type Toolbar, got fullscreen of type str" but I'm not sure how to pass anything besides strings here.

There's not any way to control this via theme. The theme files specify property values, and real underlying property type here is a list of actual tool instances. The "list of strings" API does not correspond to any property at all. It is a high level convenience that the figure initializer provides—it converts the strings to the expected tool instances up front automagically. But there is no way to specify actual instances in YAML or JSON.

Thank you! That explanation was very helpful. I guess it's easy enough to just create a list and reference that for each new figure.
